# Secure password less ssh configuration between HP-UX and Linux Suse

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I already verify the permission (700 for .ssh and 600 for ./ssh/* ) review the config for the file sshd_config, but the server continu asking for a password, this is the log:

```
nomgmpr@psoftn $ ssh -vvv ftepc@130.172.152.194
OpenSSH_5.9p1+sftpfilecontrol-v1.3-hpn13v12, OpenSSL 0.9.8q 2 Dec 2010
HP-UX Secure Shell-A.05.90.003, HP-UX Secure Shell version
debug1: Reading configuration data /opt/ssh/etc/ssh_config
debug3: RNG is ready, skipping seeding
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 130.172.152.194 [130.172.152.194] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /psdb/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /psdb/.ssh/identity-cert type -1
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/psdb/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /psdb/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /psdb/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /psdb/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /psdb/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /psdb/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /psdb/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Remote is NON-HPN aware
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1+sftpfilecontrol-v1.3-hpn13v12
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "130.172.152.194" from         file "/psdb/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /psdb/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-    v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa
debug3: RNG is ready, skipping seeding
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: AUTH STATE IS 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-    cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: REQUESTED ENC.NAME is 'aes128-ctr'
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: REQUESTED ENC.NAME is 'aes128-ctr'
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 122/256
debug2: bits set: 504/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 2f:6b:0b:9c:27:e3:64:26:d7:7c:dd:87:de:db:de:27
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "130.172.152.194" from file "/psdb/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /psdb/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host '130.172.152.194' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /psdb/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug2: bits set: 525/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /psdb/.ssh/identity (0)
debug2: key: /psdb/.ssh/id_rsa (6000000000059270)
debug2: key: /psdb/.ssh/id_dsa (0)
debug2: key: /psdb/.ssh/id_ecdsa (0)
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /psdb/.ssh/identity
debug3: no such identity: /psdb/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /psdb/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /psdb/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /psdb/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /psdb/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /psdb/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
debug3: remaining preferred: password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug2: input_userauth_info_req
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1
Password:
```

Can you help me with some tips?

Comment: Anything obvious being logged on the server side?

Comment: How many key file pairs do you have in your .ssh directory?

Answer (score 1):

The more important help can come from the server side if you have access to the server. On the server side, stop sshd. If the server side is HP-UX, `/sbin/init.d/secsh stop` will do this for you. Then you need to start sshd in debug mode using command `/usr/sbin/sshd -ddd`. At this point make sure nobody else is coming to this machine via ssh, because, sshd in debug mode will only allow one single incoming connection.

Then you go to your linux machine and issue the command `ssh -vvv hpux_server`. At that point, compare the debug outputs side by side. I am sure, in no time you will see where the problem is coming from. My bet is on the private and public ssh keys mismatch, due to file formatting but I might be wrong of course.

If you don't get it, please post the debug output from both client and the server, for everyone to see.